# Transpose and reduce different size arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some code that retrieves two arrays and divides their elements with each other. These arrays are part of an API and I have noticed that sometimes one of the two arrays(could be any one of the two), can be missing its last element, thus messing with the indexes.

When that happens, I am getting an IndexError. What is the appropriate way to handle this so that for the last element I am getting a value that makes sense, if this scenario happens. Nil for example would be fine I believe for that 4th element in the example below. Here is how it looks on the console:

```
2.7.1 :340 > f
 => [23174492.0, 30853051.0, 63763025.0]
2.7.1 :341 > n
 => [20241623.0, 28924803.0, 3213386.0, 82600678.0]
2.7.1 :342 > [f,n].transpose.map {|x| x.reduce(:/)}
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from (irb):342
        1: from (irb):342:in `transpose'
IndexError (element size differs (4 should be 3))
```

Comment: transpose needs the array lengths to match or it will throw an error https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/transpose so just check that the 2 arrays are the same length before running transpose.  [f,n].transpose.map {|x| x.reduce(:/)} unless f.size != n.size or just get the length of the 2 arrays and pop the last elements out of the longest array until the 2 array's are equal length then use transpose.

Comment: Cool yeah, I was thinking along similar lines, just thought there may be a more elegant way to do it, that's why i asked pretty much. Thanks!

Comment: Up front preemptive checking is more elegant. 1) the function does not look stupid - i.e. buggy - processing obviously invalid data. 2) "inline" checking code will read like a bloody tourniquet trying to keep together two halves of this method chaining/functional code style 3) more conducive to future change. 3) significantly improve readability